# I get: [ts] 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular

I'm taking an Angular2 course and following along. Everything I have been doing thus far for all the other exercise has worked fine until I got to creating this custom validator and this Promise code. Makes no sense to me why this would occur now.

[image]

I get: [ts] 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Can't seem to resolve this. I get my error even without adding in the setTimeout function.

Per a suggestion from someone elsewhere. I added to the tsconfig.json:
"compilerOptions": {
...
"types" : [ "core-js" ]
}

But I still get the error.

Using Visual Studio code: Version 1.10.1.
OS: Windows 10 Pro.

Here's my code:

```
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';

export class UsernameValidators 
{
    static shouldBeUnique(control: Control) 
    {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
       {            
          setTimeout(function()
          {
             if (control.value == "Dan")
                resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
             else
                resolve(null);
          }, 1000);
       });
   }
}
```

Here's the course that I am taking and a screen shot of what I am being instructed to do. The intelliSense is different from mine. It works fine and they do not get the error I get.

[image]

Here's the courses end result.

[image]

Comment: I see that you asked this in a thread on the VSCode repo (I assume it's you because the issue is literally the same as here).

Did you try the npm solution?

Do you need to compile to ES6?

Comment: No I did not ask this on that thread. I did however see something similar there. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21968

Comment: No I did not try the npm solution as I am new to this and was hesitant to do so. I'm just taking a course on this and following along in the course. I did however, try the suggestion of adding an entry to the tsconfig.json file. But that did not resolve it so I backed it out.

Comment: Yes actually I did ask this on that thread. I forgot I did so ignore the comment above regarding that.

Comment: Are you try to set `lib:["es6"]` in `tsconfig.json` compilerOptions?

Comment: Yes, I just set the es5 to es6 and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to target ES6, or else use a polyfill library like bluebird. If you are targeting ES5 in the compiler output, then it will fail like this because ES5 has no Promises.

Comment: In VS Code I additionally had to execute the command "TypeScript: Reload Project" in the command palette for VS Code to stop complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [#43546088](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43546088/1233379) (only if you're already using [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)): in case you aren't, I would suggest you to try and use them so you can normalize your compiler references and possibly fix the issue.

If you're using it, I suggest you to read [this Github thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15140) for an extensive analysis of the problem and also some workaround. To quickly recap the (IMHO) best one of them, assuming that you have this in your **package.json** file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js --global"
  }
```

Change it in the following way:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js@0.9.7+20161130133742 --global"
  }
```

So you'll force VS to get a unaffected version/build of the core-js definitions file(s). However, is highly recommended to remove the explicit version+build reference as soon as the issue will be released.

For further info regarding this issue, you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/error-ts2693-buildmap-refers-type-used-value-core-js-typescript/) on my blog.