# typescript: error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am trying to use Typescript for my AWS Lambda and i am getting the following errors where ever I use promises.

```
error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I tried using the following variations in the code

Using the Promise constructor

```
responsePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    return reject(new Error(`missing is needed data`))
                })
```

using Promise.reject

```
responsePromise = Promise.reject(new Error(`Unsupported method "${request.httpMethod}"`));
```

#### Versions

Following are the versions in my dev dependencies:

```
"typescript": "^2.2.2"
"@types/aws-lambda": "0.0.9",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.40",
"@types/node": "^7.0.12",
```

#### Contents of tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        // "typeRoots" : ["./typings", "./node_modules/@types"],
        "target": "es5",
        // "types" : [ "core-js" ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "index.ts",
        "lib/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I am using grunt-ts with the following configuration for running ts task.

```
ts: {
            app: {
                tsconfig: {
                    tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
                    ignoreSettings: true
                }
            },
...
```

I tried with the solution mentioned in [I get: [ts] 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984670/i-get-ts-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as-a-value-here) but no luck.

Comment: No return value is needed for the callback function passed in to the Promise constructor. Just get rid of `return`.

Comment: Do you mean like this?
`responsePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   reject(new Error("missing is needed data"))})` I tried it. But it did not hep with the problem.

Comment: Yes. JavaScript doesn't care whether  you return a value or not, but it won't pay attention to it. TypeScript, however, does care.

Comment: Got it. But why does tsc fails to compile any flavour of Promose.resolve or Promise.reject?

Comment: That, I don't know. How exactly is `responsePromise` declared?

Comment: @Pointy I tried to define like this. `let responsePromise: Promise<void> | Promise<any> | Promise<Error> = Promise.reject('Unknown error');` . but it did not help.

Comment: `noEmit`? http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Pointy, if the function needs to return a value the 'return' keyword is definitely required. I'm running into this problem too, and it's definitely about the fact that TypeScript is having issues handling the Promise object correctly, and has nothing to do with any of the kalyanvgopal's being wrong because his code is fine.

Comment: to those trying any of the below answers and finding no luck, make sure your `tsconfig.json` is in the right directory! mine was in a directory below the file that was giving me the ts2693 error.

Answer (score 135):

I had the same issue with the `aws-sdk` and I solved it by using `"target": "es2015"`. This is my `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `@types/aws-lambda` are out of date. Amazon ships Typescript types with the [official SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/clients/lambda.d.ts). There is no need for DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: That solved the exact error defined in the question for me and I was just importing rxjs, not even using Promis. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is probably the best answer for those who were targeting es5 to begin with. Switching from es5 to es2015 also fixed this for me as well. Be warned however, you likely will still see the error until you shut down and restart your IDE/editor. Something about the TSC (or it's watch mode) was making it appear that this wasn't fixing it when it really was, but required a restart of vscode.

Comment: update/addendum: if you want to still target es5 (for better browser support, and is important) that does still work as long as you supply this in your compiler options:

"lib" : ["es2015", "dom", "ScriptHost"],

The trick for me was realizing i had to restart VSCode editor, before it would begin working after making that change.

Answer (score 94):

Encounter the same error today and solved it with:

```
npm i --save-dev  @types/es6-promise
```

**Update:**

add:

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'
```

Comment: + and restarting VS Code helps too, after installation of the types

Comment: Erratum: It works using this line

    `import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'`;

Comment: where to add "import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'" ?

Comment: I've used this solution in the past, but it's not working for me at the moment. `import { Promise } from '../node_modules/es6-promise/es6-promise';`, however, seems to be working fine. Why would TS be unable to find the installed typings?

Answer (score 40):

I solved this by adding below code to tsconfig.json file.

```
"lib": [
    "ES5",
    "ES2015",
    "DOM",
    "ScriptHost"]
```

Comment: this worked for me, but note that the "lib" array needs to be inside of the "compilerOptions" object in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Using TypeScript 2.4.1 I had to change all of the characters in the string array to be lowercase. Then it worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Solved by changing the *target* in compilerOptions.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./public/js/app"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "public/js",
    "assets/app/polyfills.ts"
],
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
}
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is my tip. Tested with vscode 1.21.1 (on MAC)

Put below config to **tsconfig.json**

```
"lib": [
"es2016",
"dom"
]
```

into 
**compilerOptions**

**Restart IDE (this action is required :D )**

Comment: This is listed in multiple of the answers here and it **important** for sure: "Restart IDE (this action is required)"

Answer (score 11):

I got rid of this same error in `index.ts` with these combined properties:

In tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
```

And in package.json:

```
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && node index.js"
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this error but I resolved it by using this command, my ts file name is promises-fs.ts:

```
tsc promises-fs.ts --target es6 && node promises-fs.js
```

and the error is gone

Answer (score 6):

Add below line to file where error is being thrown.This should fix the issue

```
declare var Promise: any;
```

**P.S:** This is definitely not the optimal solution

Comment: This is just removing the type check for 'Promise,' rather than fixing it so Typescript finds the correct type.

Comment: This workaround does not work with Internet Explorer 11 for example. I throws an 'undefined' error when trying to use Promise. Anyway with Chrome the workaround does his job.

Comment: that's a coward way out. Why use the `TS` if you are going to do something like this. I mean what's the point then?!

Comment: I agree that this is not optimal but it is unfair to say that this declaration means that there is no point in using TS. Dropping typecheck on *one* type does not make the rest of the typechecks useless. And for me, this was the only solution that worked.

Comment: May be a dirty hack, but it's the only thing that worked for me after I tried all other solutions on this page. At least I got my code compiled and working. I dig dirty hacks that work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue until I added the following lib array in typeScript 3.0.1

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es5", "es6"],
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally tsc started working without any errors. But multiple changes. Thanks to [Sandro Keil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2713053/sandro-keil), [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) & [unional](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3505900/unional)

- Removed dt~aws-lambda
- Removed options like noEmit,declaration
- Modified Gruntfile and removed ignoreSettings

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es5",
            "es6"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "*",
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
ts: {
            app: {
                tsconfig: {
                    tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"
                }
            },
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue with typescript and the `aws-sdk`. The solve was to change the target to `es6`.

My complete `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
        compilerOptions: {
                outDir: ./dist/,
                sourceMap: true,
                noImplicitAny: true,
                module: commonjs,
                target: es6,
                jsx: react,
                allowJs: true
        },
        include: [
                ./src/**/*
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes tartgeting es6 should fix it, but then you have less browser compatibility. Most apps are still today targeting es5, because many browsers still aren't on es6 yet (as of 2017)

Comment: @user2080225 although that is true, it doesn't make my answer less correct since the original question didn't state anything about browser compatibility. Therefore this solution could still help others like it helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Please be aware that if you are running the tsc command with a file name ie:

```
tsc testfile.ts
```

then the tsconfig.json compiler configuration file is ignored.
The solution is to run either the tsc command on its own, in which case all .ts files in the directory will be compiled, unless you have edited the tsconfig.json to include a set of files.

see 'using the files property'...
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, this might be counter-intuitive but I solved this adding `esnext` to my `lib`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
        "esnext"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
  }
}
```

The FIX, as suggested by the compiler is to

> Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository in your project you might be experiencing [this recent issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15140).

A decent workaround you might use (other than waiting for an updated build of the definitions file or refactoring your TS code) is to specify an explicit version+build for the core-js typings rather than let Visual Studio pick the latest/most recent one. I found one that seems to be unaffected by this problem (in my case at least), you can use it replacing the following line from your **package.jso**n file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js --global"
  }
```

With the following one:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js@0.9.7+20161130133742 --global"
  }
```

This fixed my issue for good. However, is highly recommended to remove the explicit version+build reference as soon as the issue will be released.

For further info regarding this issue, you can also [read this blog post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/error-ts2693-buildmap-refers-type-used-value-core-js-typescript/) that I wrote on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Core-js did not work for me as it caused other issues, however, simply installing the latest version of `npm i @types/es6-promise --save-dev` got rid of the issues. The issues for me stemmed from compiling an sdk that was using rxjs. Here is the error I was getting:

```
`node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(59,60): error TS2693: Promise only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I fixed it with this configuration:

File: tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",                      
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "strict": true,                          
    "esModuleInterop": true                  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this saved me from the problem in second:

write in console this:

```
npm i --save bluebird
npm i --save-dev @types/bluebird @types/core-js@0.9.36
```

in the file where the problem is copy paste this:

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target to "ES2017" in tsconfig.json file.

this is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
/* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES2017",   /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "declaration": true,  /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,    /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",   /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true        /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

npm i --save-dev  @types/es6-promise

after up command, you'd better check tsconfig.json make sure the "target" must great than "es6". maybe tsc not support es5 yet.

Answer (score 0):

None of the up-voted answers here work for me. Here is a guaranteed and reasonable solution. Put this near the top of any code file that uses Promise...

```
declare const Promise: any;
```

Comment: No, don't do this... or just don't use the typescript if you are going to do something like this

Answer (score 0):

Having spent lot of time trying to fix this. I had no luck with any solution provide here or elsewhere.

But then later realised it wasn't so much as just solving the issue. But you also need to RESTART the VSCODE for it to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of answers here that do a lot of things. The trick however is already mentioned in several answers. Answering separately b/c I want to call it out specifically though.

The only change actually required to fix this is to change "target" to >= "es2015." Just like the error says...
What it fails to say however, if that it won't make a damn bit of difference until you RESTART the ide :(

So

1. "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es2015"
2. RESTART the IDE
3. UGH.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Using a *class* instead of a *type* for my nested dto works for me.