# ''Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

I tried to use a promise to Async call in my custom validator in the form for that I created following separate typescript file

**usernameValidators.ts**

```
import { Control } from 'angular2/common';

export class UsernameValidators {

    static shouldBeUnique(control: Control){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(control.value == "mosh")
                    resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });

                else
                    resolve(null);


            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm developing this using VS code, here I'm having red squiggly line under **Promise** and once I goto **PROBLEMS** tab, I can see

following error

[image]

how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is in your `tsconfig.json` file? If output is `es5` then you'll need to include a promise library or a shim for `es6` before you can use promises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript: error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119163/typescript-error-ts2693-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as)

Comment: can i also suggest to you to don't use function() in your ts code?

Comment: @Duncan this is my [tsconfig.json](https://kobra.io/#/e/-KqxFgKrOAyJmgUvVben) file

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi actually I'm new to angular please let me know with a example if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you specified `es5` as the target, but `es5` doesn't have a native `Promise` implementation so you also need to include some kind of shim that provides the implementation.

The simplest solution should be to include the "es2015.Promise" library in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": ["es2015.promise", "dom"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, with that approach error goes away, but here in `tsconfig.json` getting a warring [like this](http://i.imgur.com/8oausRv.png)

Comment: @kelumpriyadarshane `es2015.promise` - lower case

Comment: Strangely, for me it works only when `es` is specified als lib too, altough it's already set as target: `["es2015.promise", "es5","dom"]`. Additionally, VS Code seems to lack of reloading the file. I had to restart VS Code to make the error disappear.