# How to resolve 'Build:'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.'

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I get build error saying 'Build:'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.'.

My project target is 'ES5'. From this thread, I can resolve the issue by changing it to ES6. Is there a way to resolve the issue without changing my target?

[typescript: error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119163/typescript-error-ts2693-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as)

Thank you.

Comment: it would help if you could post a code example that fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the environment you are going to run it supports promise, you can target ES5, but add the `lib` compiler option:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
        "es2015.promise" // Or "es2015" or "es6" should work as well
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I configure tsc to find 'es6.promise' as library?  My typescript project is not management by npm.  I tried above suggestion, I get an error saying Promise is not a defined type.

Comment: How are you compiling your TypeScript code? If you are using `tsconfig.json` the above option should work. If you are running `tsc` from the command line, the option should be `--lib`. See [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 12):

To solve this without changing `lib` you have to add `@types/node` to dependencies or devDependencies this will **resolve** not only `Promise` but **all node types**.

`npm i @types/node`

Here is my lib:

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "es5",
  "dom.iterable",
  "scripthost"
]
```