# Create user data for new Firebase auth accounts in Firestore

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to create user data (name, email, phone number) in Firestore. This should be triggered with on create an authenticated user.

at `functions`-> `src`-> `index.ts`

```
// Sends email to user after signup
export { welcomeEmail } from './send_email';
// Saves user after signup
export { createUserDoc } from './save_user';
```

at `functions`-> `src`-> `save_user.ts`

```
// Firebase Config
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as firebase from "firebase-admin";
import {MD5} from "crypto-js";

export const createUserDoc = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const firebaseUser = event.data;

    // Use gravatar as default if photoUrl isn't specified in user data
    let fileEnding = "jpg";
    let photoURL = `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${MD5(firebaseUser.email).toString().toLowerCase()}.jpg?s=1024&d=robohash`;
    if (firebaseUser.photoURL) {
        fileEnding = firebaseUser.photoURL.substr(firebaseUser.photoURL.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        photoURL = firebaseUser.photoURL;
    }

    const fileName = `users/${firebaseUser.uid}/profile.${fileEnding}`;
    const profilePhotoStorageOpts = {
        destination: fileName,
        metadata: {
            contentType: `image/${fileEnding}`
        }
    };

    const user = {
        name: firebaseUser.displayName || "No Name",
        email: firebaseUser.email,
        photoUrl: `gs://${firebase.storage().bucket().name}/${fileName}`
    };

    return Promise.all([
        firebase.storage().bucket().upload(photoURL, profilePhotoStorageOpts),
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set(user)
    ]);
});
```

The goal was, for each created account I would now find a corresponding user document in Firestore and a profile image in the cloud storage.

instead I'm getting:

Property 'data' does not exist on type 'UserRecord'.ts(2339)

'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.ts(2585)

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you will see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onCreate) for the `onCreate` method, the first parameter of the handler function is a [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord.html) which does not have a `data` property.

So the first error you get is normal.

In your case, if you want, for example, to get the user's `photoURL`, you should do `event.photoURL` (Since `event` is of type `UserRecord`). Similarly, you will do `event.uid` to get the user's uid.

---

For the second error, you may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43122423/3371862 or [How to resolve 'Build:'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079719/how-to-resolve-buildpromise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as-a-va?rq=1)