# TypeScript error on typeof: "X only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Tags: typescript

What is the alternative here:

```
const MY_SET =
  (typeof Set === 'undefined') ? undefined : new Set();
```

I receive the error:

```
 error TS2693: 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453829/152543) suggests declaring an `any` var somewhere in the file. It works, but seems ugly and type unsafe.

Is there an alternative syntax?

Comment: What type declaration are you using for `Set`?

Comment: try adding es2015.collection to the list in the _lib_ option of the tsconfig.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to detect and handle older browser case where Set was not available.  Am I understanding correctly that the `--lib` options do not add Polyfills and only add declarations that don't get exposed in the compiled `.js` file.  If so, guess that is my answer.

Comment: That's correct - `--lib` is only about type declarations, it does not affect generated javascript. Compiler generates polyfills for small number of language features depending on `--target`, but Set is not one of them.

Comment: Is there a list of those compiler generated polyfills? I'm still trying to wrap my head around what TypeScript does and does not add to JavaScript. Even with the --downlevelIterators, I'm finding inconsistencies with what they've decided to support and not support (e.g., function generators but not for loop syntax on their results).

Comment: The closest I could find is this https://github.com/Microsoft/tslib, see also https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/16/typescript-2-1-external-helpers-library

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the code must be using a very old [TSConfig `compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib). Set `lib` and `target` in your `tsconfig.json` to something relatively recent, like `"es2020"`.

TypeScript is being told that your JavaScript runtime doesn't have a global `Set` class, just a general type that happens to be called `Set`. So TypeScript complaining that the code is trying to use a *runtime* operator (`typeof`) on a *type system* type (`Set`). But type system types are only development-time helpers: they don't exist at runtime.

https://www.learningtypescript.com/articles/why-increase-your-tsconfig-target goes into general context around TSConfig lib and target more.