# Property finally is missing in type Promise

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, finally

I'm pretty sure I'll be able to solve this issue by myself but if it can help somebody else I want to share and save somebody else time.

I had to add the `es6-promise` library to get rid of this error

```
Promise only result to a type, but is only used as a value here.
```

when I was trying to use Promise.all (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119163/typescript-error-ts2693-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as#43122423) ). It worked fine until now, I get an error when I'm trying to use a Promise from MongoDB.

```
Promise<whatever> is not assignable to Promise<any>
    Property 'finally' is missing in type Promise<whatever>
```

According to [this issue on es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/232) (if I got that right), the new finally property is breaking compatibility. It's there on the Promise Mongo return but not on the one I imported from es6-promise.

Any idea?

Comment: I tried to pin es6-promise to 4.1.1 and to simply remove it. I use typescript 2.8.3

Comment: Have you tried just using the build-in promise definitions ? In tsconfig: `"lib": ["es5","es2015.promise","dom", "scripthost"]`

Comment: Just tried, not working. I'm reluctant to update Typescript since I'm pretty sure that will break everything

Comment: Updated to 2.9.2, still not working (but it looks like the compiler is using `--pretty` by default now... the error is prettier and neatly colorised, but it is still there).

Comment: I was not necessarily suggesting you upgrade tsc, I was if you just need the definitions for Promises, to use the buit-in ones. You can do this even while targeting `es5` by using the libs option as above. And remove es6-promise

Comment: Oh right I haven't removed e6-promise. I'll be right back.

Comment: Yup, it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'm the one who noted that the `finally` shim was breaking Promise compatibility on that [linked issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/232#issuecomment-372413522). Nice to see this getting some attention. Here are some options:

### 1. Rely purely on the TypeScript core library's typings

**`tsconfig.json`**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["DOM","ES5","ScriptHost", "es2018.promise"]
    }
}
```

Install the shim, run the polyfill once at the start of your app, and from then on use the global `Promise` object rather than continuing to import the `Promise` class from `es6-promise`. I've found this to be the most inter-operable way.

```
npm install --save es6-promise@latest
```

Note that `es6-promise` has, for the last few releases, been bundling its own typings that conflict with the typings of TypeScript's built-in `Promise` libs.

### 2. Use an older version of `es6-promise` that doesn't include the `finally` shim

Note: Of course this means that you can't use `finally`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["DOM","ES5","ScriptHost"]
    }
}
```

Install the last version of `es6-promise` before they introduced `finally`, and use those typings:

```
npm install --save es6-promise@4.2.2 && npm install --save-dev @types/es6-promise@0.0.32
```

(Or otherwise omit those typings and add `es2015.promise` to your `compilerOptions.lib` array in `tsconfig.json`.)

Comment: Note for other people coming here: you can encounter a very similar error when you're treating a resolved promise value as a promise. This can trip people up when you're dealing with nested promises.

Comment: @Barbarrosa I think I might be encountering the problem you describe...any pointers on how to fix it?

Comment: @MaxWaterman I'm not sure about your particular situation, but generally you'd need to update the typings to reflect the non-promise value and correct accessors to avoid using properties that don't exist on the non-promise type.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a correct type definition for a `Promise` then you can just use the built-in definitions that come with typescript (I say this because you note that the promise you are actually working with has the `finally` method as expected).

To do this, remove `es6-promise` form you project and in `tsconfig` change your lib to:

```
{
    ....
    "lib": ["es5","es2015.promise","dom", "scripthost"] 
    ....
}
```

Comment: I am using typescript 2.7.2 and want to use finally in my promises. this solved it.. but what are you setting in target and module? and is there any way to update this to 2018 with my version?