# Set initially selected item in Select list in Angular7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

Set initially selected item in Select list in Angular7

I am a beginner in the angular framework. I want to set the default of a Dropdown select by value. What should be added in .ts file so that I get expected a result?

.html file :

```
<select  name="employees"   (change) = "onEdit(emp)" [(ngModel)]="employees" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let emp of employees"  [value]="emp.id">
    {{emp.fullName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

.ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {    
this.service.getEmployeenames().subscribe(actionArray => {
  this.employees = actionArray.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.payload.doc.id,
      ...item.payload.doc.data()
    } as Employee;
   })
  });     
 }
```

Suppose 3 items in dropdown select:

```
Employee1
Employee2
Employee3
```

Default I want to set to `Employee1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you may make use ng `[ngValue]`.

When you bind to `[value]`, it is usually in the format of a string, or number.

However, there may be scenarios whereby you would like to bind an entire object to your select-option. This is when ngValue comes useful.

For this example, we have binded the entire `emp` object to the option value. We have selected the first index of the `employee` array as the default selected value.

On the component.ts,

```
employee: any = undefined;
employees = [
  {fullName: 'Employee-0',id:"0"},
  {fullName: 'Employee-1',id:"1"},
  {fullName: 'Employee-2',id:"2"}
];

constructor() {
  this.employee = this.employees[1];
  console.log(this.employee)
}
```

Component.html,

```
<select  name="employees" (change) = "onEdit(emp)" [(ngModel)]="employee" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let emp of employees" [ngValue]="emp">
    {{emp.fullName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I have created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nftpdq-nhgshu?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) over here.

---

EDIT: In order to add the required validation on your code, you will need to add the required attribute on the `<select>` tag. I have also added a default placeholder on the select.

```
<select name="employeeInput" [(ngModel)]="employee" required class="form-control" #employeeInput="ngModel" >
  <option disabled [ngValue]="null">--Selected--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let emp of employees" [ngValue]="emp">
    {{emp.fullName}}
  </option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="employeeInput.control.errors?.required && isSubmitted">
    Name is required.
</div>

<div>
  <button (click)="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

`#employeeInput="ngModel"` exports `NgModel` into a local variable called employeeInput. The  with the *ngIf will show the validation error message if no options on the select are selected.

On your component.ts, I have set `employee` as `null` so that the default placeholder is selected. In addition, the `submit()` method sets `isSubmitted` as true so that the validation message will only show upon submission of form. The if condition will check if the input is selected with a value, hence the condition of `this.employeeInput.errors`.

```
@ViewChild('employeeInput') employeeInput: TemplateRef<any>;
employee: any = undefined;
isSubmitted: boolean = false;
employees = [
  {fullName: 'Employee-0',id:"0"},
  {fullName: 'Employee-1',id:"1"},
  {fullName: 'Employee-2',id:"2"}
];

constructor() {
  this.employee = null;
}

submit() { 
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  if (!this.employeeInput.errors) {
    // will only enter this block of code if the select has no errors
    // insert the rest of your firebase code
  }
```

Check out the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nftpdq-aodzsv?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html).

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. If i am not asking you more.. 1st item i wanted as  '--Select--' . In my validation part if first item '--Select--' is selected , written <div *ngIf="employees.invalid && employees.touched" class="validation-error">This field is required.</div>.         But doesnt work.. How to check for mandatory selction of item? i have also added required attribute to <select></select>

Comment: @Supritha glad to help. Just to check, when will you want the validation to fire?

Comment: Thanks! #On click of button                                                                                               In component.html  :  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">SUBMIT</button>   In component.ts : onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    let data = Object.assign({}, form.value);
    delete data.id;
    if (form.value.id == null)
      this.firestore.collection('events').add(data);
    else
      this.firestore.doc('events/' + form.value.id).update(data);
    this.resetForm(form);
    this.toastr.success('Submitted successfully', 'Event. Register');
  }

Comment: Alright, I get it! It is actually quite simple. I have updated my code, and added a new demo.

Comment: Wow! Working.. Good explanation and thanks for demo..Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind employeeId with `[(ngModel)]` not the list because you are binding the `[value]="emp.id"` to the `employeeId`

HTML Code:

```
                                                              \/\/\/\/\/
<select  name="employees" (change)="onEdit(emp)" [(ngModel)]="employeeId" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let emp of employees" [value]="emp.id">
    {{emp.fullName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

TS Code:

```
employeeId : any = "0" //  like this in your case it should be an Id of employee
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nftpdq-tekhbe)

Comment: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.  Getting this error. not sure why. .

Comment: @Supritha Share the actual code or sample data will try with that

Comment: @Supritha or you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119163/typescript-error-ts2693-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as/45631744) for your new error!