# Getting error "Property used before its initialization". I am trying to get user id from firebase so I can add it to a message object

Tags: angular, firebase

Here is my code

```
  user: firebase.default.User;
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    afAuth.user.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data;
    })
  }

  post = {
    message: 'hello world',
    uid: this.user.uid, //getting the error right here **Property 'user' used before its initialization
  }
```

This isn't making sense to me since I am initializing the user variable in the constructor. Please go easy on me I am new to angular and also somewhat new to firebase.

Comment: Its a new type check of TypeScript. Your code is fine. If your editor is using the newer version of typescript then it will give these kinds of issues. But its a good practice to follow the coding standards. For detailed description please follow this link https://mariusschulz.com/blog/strict-property-initialization-in-typescript

Comment: you can store the post variable data after this.user = data;

Comment: You can also point the project to use lower version of es library to ease the compilation. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119163/typescript-error-ts2693-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as

Comment: Thanks you guys!