# Can't use promise inside class functions in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Using the class option I planned to create a class with functions for CRUD operations in typescript. (*like CreateStudent(),updateStudent(),listStudents(),ViewStudent()*) So first I created a listStudent function

```
class student {
    listStudent (apiUrl:string) {
        this.usePromise(apiUrl).then(function(){
            console.log("api call completed");
        });
    }

    usePromise<T>(apiUrl:string):Promise<T> {
        let p: Promise<T>;
        p = new Promise(() => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            ...
        }
            ...
    });
    return p;
    }
}
let s:student = new student();
s.listStudent("api/list.php");
```

Here initially I tried like this

```
usePromise(apiUrl:string):Promise {}
```

I got an error saying

> generic type 'Promise' requires 1 arguement

So I read about generic types and then I implemented it in the usePromise function. Now I am getting an error on promise object creation `new Promise()` saying

> Promise only refers to a type but is being used as a variable here

- Why this error, I declared promise correctly as the return type creating object of that type?
- Instead of this, wherever I try to create a promise object inside any class function I get the same Error?

Comment: have you checked out these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984670/i-get-ts-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as-a-value-here and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119163/typescript-error-ts2693-promise-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-as?

Comment: does it compile? or the tslint is giving you error even before compiling?

Comment: I just used the plain ts file and run it using the tsc command.

Comment: It seems to be fine with the target ES6, but now shows error on XMLHttprequest and console.log

Comment: I updated my code with these compiler options 

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es6","dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
        },
    "files": [
        "student.ts"
    ]
}`